# Manually loading of assemblies and dependencies at runtime (nuget dependencies & FileNotFoundException)

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-standard, assembly-loading

I currently have an issue with loading assemblies at runtime using `Assembly.LoadFrom(String)`.
While the specified assembly is loaded just fine, referenced third-party assemblies (e.g. nuget packages) are not loaded when the targeted framework is either `netcoreapp` or `netstandard`.

To figure out the problem i have created a simple solution consisting of three projects.
Each project contains exactly one class.
I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` as a nuget example here but it could be any other assembly.

**ClassLibrary0.csproj**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net20;netstandard1.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

```cs
namespace ClassLibrary0 {
    public class Class0 {

        public System.String SomeValue { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**ClassLibrary1.csproj**

Has a package reference to `Newtonsoft.Json` via `nuget`.
Has a reference to additional assembly `ClassLibrary0` depending on `TargetFramework` (shitty conditional `ItemGroups`).

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net20;net35;net40;net45;net451;net452;net46;net461;net462;net47;net471;net472;netstandard1.0;netstandard1.1;netstandard1.2;netstandard1.3;netstandard1.4;netstandard1.5;netstandard1.6;netstandard2.0;netcoreapp1.0;netcoreapp1.1;netcoreapp2.0;netcoreapp2.1</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net20' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='net35' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='net40' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='net45' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='net451' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='net452' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='net46' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='net461' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='net462' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='net47' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='net471' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='net472'">
    <Reference Include="ClassLibrary0">
      <HintPath>..\net20\ClassLibrary0.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard1.0' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard1.1' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard1.2' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard1.3' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard1.4' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard1.5' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard1.6' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard2.0'">
    <Reference Include="ClassLibrary0">
      <HintPath>..\netstandard1.0\ClassLibrary0.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp1.0' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp1.1' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp2.0' OR '$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp2.1'">
    <Reference Include="ClassLibrary0">
      <HintPath>..\netstandard1.0\ClassLibrary0.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```cs
namespace ClassLibrary1 {
    public class Class1 {

        public System.String SomeValue { get; set; }

        public Class1() {
            var tmp = new ClassLibrary0.Class0();
            var tmp2 = new Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultJsonNameTable();
        }

    }
}
```

**ClassLibrary2.csproj**

Has a project reference to `ClassLibrary1`.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net20;net35;net40;net45;net451;net452;net46;net461;net462;net47;net471;net472;netstandard1.0;netstandard1.1;netstandard1.2;netstandard1.3;netstandard1.4;netstandard1.5;netstandard1.6;netstandard2.0;netcoreapp1.0;netcoreapp1.1;netcoreapp2.0;netcoreapp2.1</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```cs
namespace ClassLibrary2 {
    public class Class2 {

        public System.String SomeValue { get; set; }

        public Class2() {
            var tmp = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();
        }

    }
}
```

After running `dotnet restore` and rebuilding the solution the root problem can be observed in the output directories:

**The Problem:**

- Copies of `ClassLibrary0.dll` are present in all output directories (=> references to third-party are good).
- Copies of `ClassLibrary1.dll` are present in all output directories of `ClassLibrary2` (=> project references are good too).
- Copies of `Newtonsoft.Json` are only present in `net` output directories but are missing in all `netcoreapp` and `netstandard`.
- All `netcoreapp` and `netstandard` output directories contain a `*.deps.json` file that correctly mentions the `Newtonsoft.Json` package as a dependency.

A call to `Assembly.LoadFrom(String)` however won't load these dependencies to `Newtonsoft.Json` in case of `netcoreapp` and `netstandard`.
This results in `FileNotFoundException` at runtime after running code from the specified loaded assemblies.

**What i've tried:**

I am trying to resolve those by attaching to the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event but so far i'm out of luck.
Those `*.deps.json` don't contain a location path of the dependency.

I've tried looking for the assembly in all the locations within the `Path` environment variable but the nuget package location doesn't seem to be listed there.
The location on all my machines seems to be `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\package-name\version\`.
However i'm not 100% positive that this will always be the correct location for nuget packages on all machines that might execute my code.

**The actual question:**

Is there a solid way to resolve nuget dependencies at runtime when manually loading assemblies?

**Restrictions:**

- This needs to be an offline solution, no downloading of package versions on the fly.
- Cannot rely on `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` in the original projects.
- Cannot rely on me having references to the dependencies in question.
  The whole point of doing this is to be able to dynamically load assemblies that i can't know about at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem by writing my own NuGet package resolver, which looks for the appropriate package at runtime. I haven't had the time for a proper documentation yet but it's already on my plate. Resolving at runtime requires to attach to AppDomain.AssemblyResolve with something like that:

```cs
private Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
    if(AssemblyResolver.Nuget.TryResolve(args, out IEnumerable<FileInfo> files)) {
        foreach(FileInfo file in files) {
            if(AssemblyHelper.TryLoadFrom(file, out Assembly assembly)) {
                return assembly;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This requires the use of my [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nuclear.Assemblies/) which contains the resolver and some helpers. There is also an [article](https://mikelimasierra.net/index.php/2020/07/23/resolving-cached-nuget-packages-at-runtime/) that goes into the details and design decisions of the resolver.
I realize that `dotnet publish` will also copy any dependencies but this is a special edge case.