# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient' in .NET standard Library

Tags: c#, ado.net, .net-standard

I've created a .NET standard library 2.0 which uses `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` Version=1.12.20106.1. I'm referring to this library in the console application (.NET Framework 4.7.2). While making call, I'm getting the error shown below, even though I've added an assembly reference. Can anyone help please?

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=1.12.20106.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=1.12.20106.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5"}

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that in the full error you will see something like

> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the
> assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

When I experience a similar problem and run a unit test in the debugger then I see this sort of thing in the unit test output Pre-bind state information

```
Pre-bind state information
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=2.0.20168.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Dev2/MyApp/UnitTests/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : MyApp, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Dev2\myapp\UnitTests.dll.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 2.0.20168.4 redirected to 1.12.20106.1.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=1.12.20106.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Dev2/MyApp/UnitTests/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

The issue is an assembly binding issue the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540720/how-do-i-expose-a-netstandard2-0-library-with-com-for-use-in-vb6) may help. Don't worry that it mentions VB6 the actual issue is independent of that.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is only useful if your `netstandard2.0` library has referenced `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` as a NuGet package and the referred assembly is not copied over on build.

You may have to use `dotnet publish` to have the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` assembly copied. It's something that I stumbled upon lately and that I had to fix [using a custom resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63061840/9595496). You shouldn't use that resolver but you should check if publishing your application and library helps the issue.

Comment: It think it must have been copying because fixing the assembly binding solved the problem.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that the problem has already been solved since the author hasn't responded to anything yet.